# How to update key and value name in dictionary using for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
{'sub_type': 'additive', 'data_type': 'Number', 'value': False, 'field_type': 'measure'}
```

I need to iterate through key, value pairs and change the key and value name,

for example

```
if key=='sub_type',
```

the key name should get updated to "`type`", and

```
if value== 'additive',
```

the value name should get updated to "`add`"

Comment: Add your current code/approach as well

Comment: for keys,values in your_dict.items():

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer That won't work because you can't modify the dictionary you're iterating over.

Comment: It needs to be `for key, value in list(your_dict.items()):` so that you're iterating over a list rather than a generator tied to the dictionary.

Comment: You can't replace a key directly. If you want to replace a key you need to delete the old key and add the new key with the original value.

Comment: Do you have to modify the dictionary in place or can you create a new dictionary? You could use a dictionary comprehension for that.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I did not pay attention and thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Iterating-and-updating a mapping is pretty gnarly and Python certainly has no support specifically for that, *especially* when you want to update not just the values but the *keys* as well: that translates to changing the internal layout of the dictionary on the fly, which affects the order of iteration for instance (you'd `pop()` each key and reinsert whatever replacement made sense, but then depending on the mapping you might have the issue of trying to replace keys you had not popped yet resulting in inconsistent behaviour).

Technically possible but generally a very bad idea.

The better approach is *usually* to just create a new dict from the old one e.g.

```py
transformed = dict(
    (
        "type" if key == "sub_type" else key,
        "add" if value == "additive" else value
    )
    for key, value in original.items()
)
```

Although for the specific case where you want to replace *one* (key, value) pair if it's present, you can just `pop()` the offending key then reinsert the replacement e.g.

```py
if val := original.pop("sub_type", None):
    # convert additive to add, leave other types as-is
    if val = "additive":
        val = "add"
    original["type"] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

**rename key:**

```
In [1626]: d = {'sub_type': 'additive', 'data_type': 'Number', 'value': False, 'field_type': 'measure'}

In [1628]: d['type'] = d.pop('sub_type')
```

**rename value:**

```
In [1630]: for k,v in d.items():
      ...:     if v == 'additive':
      ...:         d[k] = 'add'
      ...:
```

**Output:**

```
In [1631]: d
Out[1631]: {'data_type': 'Number', 'value': False, 'field_type': 'measure', 'type': 'add'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if key =='sub_type' and value == 'additive':
        d[key] = 'add'
        d["type"] = d.pop(key)
    else:
        break
```